# select distinct parent with multiple children

Tags: linq

```
public class Vehicle {
    public string Type
    public List<Color> Colors;
}

public class Result {
    public string Type
    public string Color;
}
```

I get a list of `Result`'s from a query that looks like this:

```
Car   ->  Red
Car   ->  Blue
Boat  ->  Brown
Boat  ->  Yellow
Boat  ->  Green
Plane ->  White
```

I want to select this list Into a `List<Vehicle>` with LINQ. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var List<Vehicle> = results.Select(v => new Vehicle
    {
    Type = v.Type;
    Colors = new List<Color> { new Color = v.Color }
    }
```

I'm sure I need to use some kind of group here but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like should go via a `GroupBy` call:

```
var query = input.GroupBy(x => x.Type, x => x.Color)
                 .Select(g => new Vehicle { Type = g.Key, Colors = g.ToList() })
                 .ToList();
```

Note that there's another overload of `GroupBy` which would allow you to skip the `Select` call, but I think it's simpler to do it this way. Let me know if you want the alternative form.

Note that if you don't really need these in `Vehicle` objects, you could just use a `Lookup`:

```
var lookup = input.ToLookup(x => x.Type, x => x.Color);

foreach (var color in lookup["Car"])
{
    // ...
}
```

That's handy if you only need the results within the specific method that you're querying it, but creating a `List<Vehicle>` would make more sense if you're propagating the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
results.GroupBy(r => r.Type)
       .Select(g => new Vehicle { 
                                   Type = g.Key, 
                                   Colors = t.Select(p => p.Color).ToList()
                                })
       .ToList()
```

Comment: That''s grouping by *colour*, with each element in the group being the full result. I think you want something more like my answer.

Comment: Right, that will work - although I think it's simpler if you make each grouping just a grouping of the colours. I'd also *strongly* advise the use of linebreaks and whitespace to add to readability :)

Comment: I edited the post, I agree that grouping by two fields have less letters, but will not change because this was my initial answer